# Shutdown ExecutorService gracefully when main-thread completes

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice

In a utility library i am creating a ExecutorService

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

The main thread will then post some tasks to this ExecutorService. When the main-thread completes i would like to shutdown the ExecutorService to allow the application to exit.

Problem is i can only change the code in the utility-library. One option I considered was to use daemon-threads. But then it will abruptly shutdown before the tasks posted to the service can complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Runtime#addShutdownHook()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) to add a shutdown hook to the current runtime.

E.g.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        es.shutdown();
        try {
            es.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.info("during await",e);
        }
    }
});
```

Do this upon construction/initialization of your utility class.

Comment: Almost worked. :) If the main-thread is nice enough to call System.exit(0); at the end of execution. However the users of this library can not be trusted to  do that :(

Comment: If the enduser don't want to shutdown gracefully, there's nothing to do against. Microsoft for example knows that very good. Best what you can do is to save some information about the processes somewhere in [user prefs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) and lookup it when the program starts again and then eventually inform the user as in "The program seems to have ended unexpectedly during previous run, here are some unfinished processes [...] do you want to re-run them?" and so on.

Comment: Maybe there is some way to know that the main-thread has nothing left to execute?

Answer (score 3):

`shutdownHook` will not work unless you make your executor a daemon thread. Here is the reason

`shutdownhook` is started when JVM starts exiting and JVM will not exit unless you call `es.shutDown()` so its a deadlock.

I dont know why making daemon executor didn't work. It should. A daemon executor will not shutdown until all threads started by the main class finished executing(unless they are also daemon)

try this code when creating executor

```
   ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor( new ThreadFactory() {
        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final ExecutorService executor;

Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            if (!executor.awaitTermination(SHUTDOWN_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                // Optional: Log that the executor still had tasks to process after waiting the specified time.
                Logger.log("Executor did not terminate within the specified time.");

                // Optional: Attempt to forcefully terminate the executor's worker threads.
                List<Runnable> droppedTasks = executor.shutdownNow();
                Logger.log("Executor was abruptly shut down. " + droppedTasks.size() + " tasks will not be executed.");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Handle interruption while waiting for termination (if needed).
        }
    }
});
```

Note:

- The awaitTermination method is used with an optional timeout to wait
  for the orderly termination of tasks.
- Optional log statements provide information about the termination
  status and any tasks that may not have completed.
- The shutdownNow method is called to forcefully terminate the
  executor's worker threads, along with logging information about the
  dropped tasks.

Additionally, it's important to note that this solution is effective when handling interrupts to the Java process or when the ExecutorService consists solely of daemon threads. If non-daemon threads are present and haven't completed, the JVM may not attempt to shutdown, and therefore, shutdown hooks won't be invoked. In such cases, if the shutdown is part of a discrete application lifecycle, the shutdown code should be placed at the appropriate location where the program is designed to terminate, rather than within a shutdown hook.